# SQL Server - Delete Rows Efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following `PipelineArchives` table in a SQL Server 2012 Standard  database (recovery model is "Simple"):

[image]

The table holds archived data in the `Body` column. This has grown over time and is now contains 11,914 rows with a total of 53gb of data. I'd like to execute a query that deletes all rows that have a `CreatedOn` value prior to current date - 3 months.

I tried running

```
DELETE FROM PipelineArchives 
WHERE CreatedOn < MyDate
```

When the `MyDate` criteria results in a few rows then the query executes ok from SSMS in a few seconds. However, increasing the date to give a 229 rows took 30 seconds.

Is there a more efficient way to delete the rows?

Comment: Sorry - what is EAV?

Comment: copy rows that are > current date - 3 months into another table. Delete original table, rename....

Comment: [EAV = Entity Attribute Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increment the delete, it will prevents locks on the table and allow other transactions to run. It will use more CPU and memory but its more proficient.

```
DECLARE @archiveId BIGINT

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PipelineArchives WHERE CreatedOn < MyDate) > 0
BEGIN

   SELECT TOP 1 @archiveId = PipelineArchiveId
   FROM PipelineArchives 
   WHERE CreatedOn < MyDate

   DELETE PipelineArchives 
   WHERE PipelineArchiveId = @archiveId

END
```

Comment: Counting the entries each time is less efficient than checking whether a row exists for the condition (`WHERE EXISTS(SELECT ...)`). Also: `DELETE TOP (1) ...` instead of selecting the ID first.

Comment: TT you are correct, you dont really want to count the production table every single time. However the logic is the proficient way. You can change the loop and using a @counter variable.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the right thing is to do the reverse.

Create a new table `PipelineArchivesNew` and copy rows from `PipelilneArchives` `where CreatedOn >= MyDate`. Once you have all the data you need in the new table, rename `PipelineArchives` to `PipelineArchivesOld` and `PipelineArchivesNew` to `PipelineArchives`. Then drop `PipelineArchivesOld`.

This may or may not be a good solution for you depending on how the system is setup.

Comment: Very bad idea. If this is your production table. What about your Indexes, triggers or security permission on the table. None of this is copied across, you have to setup it again.

Answer (score 0):

also you can try without variable:

```
SET ROWCOUNT 5

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PipelineArchives WHERE CreatedOn < MyDate) > 0
BEGIN
   DELETE PipelineArchives 
   FROM PipelineArchives 
   WHERE CreatedOn < MyDate
END

SET ROWCOUNT 0
```